# I've two different react native packages which require different android compileSdkVersion, how do I fix this?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I use react-native-music-control and react-native-navigation(by wix) , rnmc requires compilesdkversion 23 and buildToolsVersion '23.0.1' whereas rnn requires compilesdkversion 25 and buildToolsVersion '25.0.0', rnn does not work with 25.0.0/25 and rnn won't work with 23/23.0.1 . I don't have much experience with android so I'm not sure how to fix this, any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `build.gradle` in your projects root directory

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 25
            buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
            defaultConfig {
                targetSdkVersion 25
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to modify in my case